# $a^b+b^c+c^a$ is a multiple of 8 if and only if $a+b+c$ is multiple of 8

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a, b, c$ are odd natural numbers. Is "$a^b+b^c+c^a$ is a multiple of 8 if and only if $a+b+c$ is multiple of 8" right?

I don't know how to begin, please help me.

Comment: If $a,b,c$ are $8$ then $a+b+c$ and $a^b + b^c+c^a$ are always odd so they are never mulitple s of eight.  Was this a trick question.?

Comment: a, b, c are odd numbers.

Comment: Right.  So $a + b + c$ is odd.  And $a^b + b^c + c^a$ is also odd.  Neither can be a multiple of $8$.

Comment: Oh.... I typoed "8" when I meant "odd".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a trick question.

Unicorns eat popcorn if and only leprechauns fly airplanes.

Proof:  unicorns eat popcorn, and leprechauns fly airplanes are always false and statements that are always false are equivalent.

If $a,b,c$ are odd then $a+b+c$ is odd and never divisible by $8$ and $a^b + b^c + c^a$ is also odd and never divisible by $8$.

Comment: "Every unicorn eats popcorn" and "every leprechaun flies airplanes" are both true statements if there are no unicorns or leprechauns.

Comment: Hmm....  It's ambiguous.  I was taking it as "there are unicorns that eat popcorn".  But you are right.  "If $a$ is a unicorn, then $a$ eats popcorn' is true.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For integer $n,$

$$(2n+1)^2=8\cdot\dfrac{n(n+1)}2+1\equiv1\pmod8$$

So for odd integers $a,b;$

$$a^b\equiv a\pmod8$$

Answer (score 0):

Examine the ‘if’ requirement of the proof (this is usually the easiest part of a proof). For this we require in the first instance that $8\mid a+b+c$. Now $a$, $b$, and $c$ are odd numbers, so have the form $a=2l+1$, $b=2m+1$, $c=2n+1$. Look at their sum modulo $8$:
$$a+b+c=2(l+m+n)+3\equiv\pm1,\pm3\pmod{8}$$
and so $8\nmid a+b+c$ as this congruence is never $0$ modulo $8$. (To see why allow $l+m+n$ take the values $0$ through $7$ in the congruence and check whether the answer is divisible by $8$-note you only need to actually check the multiples $2\times0$ to $2\times3$, after which the congruences repeat.) So a false start ‘disproving’ the claimed hypothesis!